# How to change Powershell Set-Location behavior?

Tags: powershell

Let's say i have a folder named `C:\PROG`.
In Powershell, if i type `CD c:\prog`, it changes to correct location, but somehow it stores location internally as `C:\prog`,  instead of `C:\PROG`.

Is there a way to make Powershell "post process" location change to correct case internally?

Comment: what are you talking about? the prompt in the ISE console? the prompt in one of the other consoles?

Comment: You are aware that Windows is case insenisitive, right? So there is no difference between those two Paths.  If you want to store them a specific way then you should use string functions to do exactly that.

Comment: I guess you're using `Windows PowerShell`, right? Use `PowerShell 7` (or 6) and you get the expected result out of the box. The only workaround in Windows PowerShell is to use `sl (get-item C:\temp\test\).target[0]` (The trailing backslash is important, otherwise .target is null!)

Comment: Well, i was using version 5. After trying version 7 as @swbbi suggested, i can confirm that it works correctly now.